# Which directories in React JS should be publicly accessible?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am following the tutorial here:

https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr

The tutorial is a bit unclear in places where exactly files are supposed to go. But it seems like it is suggesting I structure my directories like this:

```
/react-hello-world
    /node_modules
    package.json
    /src
        /client
            /app
                /AwesomeComponent.jsx
                /index.jsx
            index.html
            /public
                bundle.js
    webpack.config.js
```

I am a bit confused as to which directories should be publicly accessible. Should it be the src directory, the client directory, or the public directory? I would have thought the public directory should be the only one open to the Internet. However, the index.html file is placed outside of the public directory. This leads me to think it should be the client directory that should be made accessible to the Internet. But, then that would mean the app directory is publicly available as well. Shouldn't the app directory be hidden from public view?

Comment: None of these *need* to be accessible. I think ideally you move the generated files somewhere where your webserver can serve them. Where that is is really up to you.

Comment: Just bundled files and root HTML file should be publicly accessible(such as bundle.js and index.html).

Comment: Ideally, you'd load one index.html, one vendor.bundle.js(with npm modules compiled), and then a custom .js with your own code. That's an easy way to do it, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **DEVELOPMENT** environment where you take advantage from NodeJS to end up with one single javascript file called `bundle.js` , that should be integrated in your **PRODUCTION** environment. and that's why you are using webpack .

Thus, no need to seek for PUBLIC directories since not the whole project will be hosted , but only `bundle.js` , `index.html` as well as assets if any (images, fonts. ...)

Answer (score 0):

Webpack-config.js is placing the bundle.js in public folder and you can also make webpack to move the index.html to public folder.

Ideally you can change the location of public folder in the webpack-config.js to be outside src. It would be more easier for you.

Then once you run webpack through npm you will get final files, take those and use it in your html.

Comment: You did not specify "how" it would be easier for me.

Comment: You have an option to move output files by using output path in config. You can place it outside src to reduce confusion. Right now you have it inside the src folder structure.